# Evaluation to true using DSolve - syntax errors?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

Probably a stupid question, apologies, but I am getting an annoying error when I try to evaluate the following simple PDE

$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = d \frac{\partial^2C}{\partial x^2}$ between $0$ and $L$ when $\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}(0,t) = \frac{\partial C}{\partial x}(L,t) = 0$ and $C(x,0) = 10e^{-k(L-x)}$. I've tried the following but keep getting an error about my first boundary condition evaluating to true. There must be something wrong with how I've written it, but I am driven demented trying to find it. Can anyone clear up where I've messed up?

```
DSolve[{D[C[x, t], t] - d*D[C[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0, 
    D[C[x, t], x] /. x -> 0 == 0 , D[C[x, t], x] /. x -> L == 0 , 
  C[x, 0] == 10 Exp[-k*(L - x)]}, C[x, t], {x, t}]
```

Comment: Move the replacements to the end of the equations, i.e. change `/. x -> L == 0` to `== 0/. x -> L`. Also `C` is a reserved symbol in *Mathematica*; use `c`. In general, you should use lower-case letters for user-defined symbols, because all *Mathematica* functions begin with capital letters. The reason this is a problem is that `==` binds "harder" than `/.`. Meditate on the outputs after evaluating the following two expressions: `b a == b /. a -> 1` and `b a /. a -> 1 == b`.

Comment: At least in V9 the docs state: _"The heat equation is parabolic, but it is not considered here because it has a nonvanishing non-principal part, and the algorithm used by DSolve is not applicable in this case."_

Comment: @belisariusisforth. Yes: once the syntax issues are fixed, `DSolve` returns unevaluated in V10. WHere did you find that in the documentation? I'm looking to see if it's the same in V10.

Comment: @march Last sentence here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DSolveSecondOrderPDEs.html

Comment: @belisariusisforth. Yeah, that's still there in my V10 documentation.

Comment: Thanks for this folks - yeah, now with fixed code it won't evaluate in V10 either. A shame, wanted to use it to check some answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is worth an answer, since it has to do with the subtleties of precedence of `Infix` operators. Consider the following two evaluations:

```
b a == b /. a -> 1
b a /. a -> 1 == b
(* True *)
(* b (1 == b) *)
```

The reason these outputs are different is that `==` binds "harder" (there's correct terminology that I'm missing here) than `/.`. The `FullForm` of these expressions looks like this:

```
Hold[b a == b /. a -> 1] // FullForm
Hold[b a /. a -> 1 == b] // FullForm
(* Hold[
    ReplaceAll[Equal[Times[b, a], b], Rule[a, 1]]
   ] *)
(* Hold[
    ReplaceAll[Times[b,a],Rule[a,Equal[1,b]]]
    ] *)
```

Simplifying a bit, this means that in the first case, you are replacing `a` for `1` in the expression

```
b a == b
```

which turns it into `b == b`, which evaluates to `True`. In the second case, you are replacing `a` with `b == 1` in the expression

```
b a
```

which evaluates to `b*(1 == b)`.

---

So, in your case, for instance, when you do

```
D[c[x, t], x] /. x -> 0 == 0
```

The last part of the expression is interpreted on its own as `Equal[0, 0]` (or `0 == 0`), which evaluates to `True`. After that evaluation, `x` gets replaced by `True` in the expression `D[c[x, t], x]`, so that you get

```
D[c[True, t], True]
```

which then is shown as

```
Derivative[1,0][c][True,t]
```

---

Just for fun, let's see why no error is thrown:

```
D[True^2, True]
(* 2*True *)
```

`D` has no problem thinking of `True` as a variable and taking a derivative with respect to it. These won't work however:

```
D[a + 1, 1]
D[a + b, a + b]
```

Comment: Cheers for this! Seems PDE not solvable by DSolve, alas...

Comment: @DRG. Yep. Do it numerically!

Answer (score 1):

The just released version of `DSolve` is more powerful than the old.  With

```
$Version
(* "10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)" *)
```

it now produces a solution.

```
DSolve[{D[C[x, t], t] - d*D[C[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0, (D[C[x, t], x] /. x -> 0) == 0,
   (D[C[x, t], x] /. x -> L) == 0, C[x, 0] == 10 Exp[-k*(L - x)]}, C[x, t], {x, t}][[1, 1]]

(* C[x, t] -> (10 - 10/E^(k*L))/(k*L) + 
   (2*Inactive[Sum][(10*E^(-(k*L) - (d*Pi^2*t*K[1]^2)/L^2)*
   (-1 + (-1)^K[1]*E^(k*L))*k*L^2*Cos[(Pi*x*K[1])/L])/
   (k^2*L^2 + Pi^2*K[1]^2), {K[1], 1, Infinity}])/L *)
```

Note that `Sum` is `Inactive`.  Activating it causes Mathematica to attempt to do the sum explicitly, and it still is trying on my computer.  Nonetheless, I think that this formal solution is quite useful.